# VBA6 type mismatch on parameter array

Tags: arrays, vba, parameters

The following (highly simplified) code produces a **`type mismatch: array expected`** on the call to evalexp for parameter xabc. Why?

```
Public nfa() As String
Public rules() As String

Sub BuildNFA(xabc () As String)
Dim x
ReDim xnfa(5, 10)
x = evalexp(0, xabc)
End Sub

Function evalexp(rnb As Integer, xyz() As String) As String
  xyz(rnb, replnode).name = "replnode"
evalregexp = ""
End Function
```

Comment: I get a compile error that `name` in `xyz(rnb, replnode).name` is an invalid qualifier. What are you doing??

Comment: Firstly, remove space from `xabc ()`. Secondly, arrays don't have `name` property. Lastly, I don't understand what is going on in your code.

Comment: Sorry. Misprint. The line with xyz should be xyz(rnb, replnode) = "replnode".

Comment: as I said, the coide given is simplified froiml the much more involved real code. The line with xyz sould read as xyz(rnb, replnode) = "replnode".

Comment: My point is, the code given in my post is (in my view) perfectly valid, but does not compile. This impacts on the real code of about 10000 lines.(Note: the real code worked correctly with just one (dynamic) array. Now, it needs to be extended for multiple arrays, so that the procedures it contains need to pass an array reference to sub procs and functions - This is nor accepted by the compiler).

Comment: However, thanks ENIAC: the blank before the () was the culprit. Never thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

Xyz is declared as () but used as(,). I.e you declare a 1d array then try to use it as a 2d array. Additionally xyz is declared as string,but you try to access a name property which will not exist. Please install the Rubberduck VBA addin and learn to use its code inspections.

Comment: thanks. My original problem is solved. Please do not investigate the logic of the code given in my post. It was overly simplified from the actual code. And apparently misleading. The original problem was the blank between the array name and the indices, which is NOT diagnosed correctly by the compiler (type mismatch, indeed!)